# Accessing ASP.NET controls dynamically from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

here's what I mean:

I have a few controls, for example,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDate1" runat="server" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDate2" runat="server" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDate3" runat="server" />
```

in my javascript, I want to do something like this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    something[i] = document.getElementById("<%= ddlDateRange" + i + ".ClientID %>");
}
```

any way I can make this work, or any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Put your dropdown lists into an array. Then you can populate a javascript array like so

```
var dropDownListIds = [];
<% foreach (DropDownList ddl in myListOfDropDowns) { %>
dropDownListIds.push('<%= ddl.ClientID %>');
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use jQuery and just do something like:

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddl" ID="ddlDate1" runat="server" />
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddl" ID="ddlDate2" runat="server" />
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddl" ID="ddlDate3" runat="server" />
```

---

```
$('.ddl').each(function(){
    var ddl = $(this);
});
```

Comment: You can call just `$('select')`

Comment: @abatishchev, you'd have to assume there aren't any other DropDownLists on the page that he doesn't want included.

Comment: Another option: `$('#someDiv > select')`

Comment: @abatishchev, I like that approach and it's probably how i'd have done it if it were my code. Another would be $("select [id*='ddlDate']")